# How TopMost work when is set to true then back to it's previous state

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a legacy C# winforms application and today I have found this code:

```
// get our current "TopMost" value (ours will always be false though)
bool top = TopMost;
// make our form jump to the top of everything
TopMost = true;
// set it back to whatever it was
TopMost = top;
```

It makes the current form pop-up, but it seems completely silly to me (even with the additional comments). I have tried it in a small isolated winforms application, and it seems to me that it can be safely replaced with a simple call to `Focus` method.

Am I wrong, or I can replace it and still sleep well tonight?

I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: What harm does it cause you? Are you trying to fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: @CaiusJard it does no harm, I just want to clean some code, and it seems very redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not Focus the window. From MSDN:

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or **the Activate method for forms.**

Perhaps your original author didn't know about activate, or perhaps he had another topmost form in his app that was causing some nuisance, but this has since gone away and this method of popping to the fore is a remnant.. Can you safely replace it with Activate? We don't know enough about the app UI to be certain; on the face of it I would say yes, but I've also said if the existing code works as per expectation there seems little mileage to be gained by changing it, and possibly some loss of functionality if the app acquires other topmost forms on the future. I'm sure your time could be better spent on other parts! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess this is the right and complete answer to my question! However maybe I will try to replace it with `Activate` and send the application to testing to see if the functionality has changed, and maybe edit the question to show the results. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar in one of the legacy project I was working with. The code was like :

```
//The form was by-default TopMost 
TopMost = false;
//some codes
MessageBox.Show("something goes here");
//some codes
TopMost = true;
```

This was done just to keep the `MessageBox` on top, as MessageBoxes shows up behind the TopMost form. When instead of this they could have used `MessageBox.Show(this, "something goes here");` without re-setting the `TopMost` property

So I feel something similar is happening here

Answer (score 0):

It may your program save it properties in a file or other place when closing and reload them on loading form, in this case your above code may helpful, in other cases I don't think it can be useful.
For example you change TopMost property to True and close your form or your program if it saved in a place, when you running your app or loading this form again you can have a TopMost form without changing it's value.

Comment: The form does not close and reload, it is just focused when the code is run, so there is no event of close and load involved.

Comment: If your program don't save this property as a setting you can remove that from your code.

Comment: But do you even understand what that block of code does on a form?